# assembly program to find the minimum and maximum value in the vector

Tags: assembly

**You should write an assembler program that finds the smallest and largest value in a vector**. In assembler, a vector (array) consists of elements that lie one after the other in memory. The vector itself is addressed with the address of its first element, and the number of elements contained in the vector is not known if you only have the address of the vector. Thus, one must either find out the number of elements in some other way (eg a parameter), or if one terminates the vector with a special value that must not occur in the vector itself (eg as the value zero that ends a string). for Atmel SAM3X8E processor

NAME      main
PUBLIC    main
SECTION   .text : CODE(2)
THUMB
main

NOP. ; <­­-- you should wright the code here

B main ; <­­-- rows of program code

STOP B STOP

ALIGNROM 2

DATA vector

```
 DC32 14, 25, 2, 27, 3
 DC32 22, 13, 4, 24, 6
 DC32 26, 18, 8, 15, 9
 DC32 28, 10, 7, 17, 5
```

Comment: *You should write an assembler program* isn't a Stack Overflow question, it's a demand / command.  No thank you.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual question here; so I'm going to assume you're asking for some guidance on how to write the code for your homework assignment.

The first thing you'll want to do is break it down into logical pieces. For example, from the requirements it should be relatively obvious that you will need:

- a loop (e.g. "for each element in the array { ... } ")
- something to keep track of the "current minimum"
- something to keep track of the "current maximum"
- something to update the current minimum and current maximum if/when an element is found that contains a value that is less than the current minimum or greater than the current maximum

Once you've identified the logical pieces, you can work on them one at a time. For example, you can start by writing some assembly for the loop (without caring about any of the other pieces) and test it to make sure it works (e.g. make sure it doesn't crash or loop forever or...).

Note that this is mostly important to avoid being overwhelmed by stuff you're not familiar with yet, and so that if you do get stuck you can ask people for help with a specific problem (e.g. maybe like "Why does this comparison of 2 integers not do what I thought it should" with a copy of your code).